Swift Multidatepicker doesn't recognize dates loaded from Firebase
I have an issue where when dates are loaded from firebase into my MultiDatePicker, the onChange function does not recognize dates that are already in the "selectedDates" array, instead re-adding them to the array. I.e. if I have loaded July 19th into the multidatePicker, it displays on the calendar, but clicking it doesn't remove July 19th from the "selectedDates array". This is the code for the view:
        VStack {
            MultiDatePicker("Select dates", selection: $selectedDates)
                .padding()
                .onChange(of: selectedDates) { oldValue, newValue in
                    saveDates(dates: selectedDates)
                 }
            List(savedDates, id: \.self) { date in
                Text("\(date, formatter: dateFormatter)")
            }
            .listStyle(.plain)
        }
        .onAppear {
            loadSavedDates()
        }

Where selectedDates is a state variable:
@State var selectedDates: Set<DateComponents> = []

If nothing is on Firebase, the selection and deselection of dates happens fine, but if I am loading dates from firebase then the multidatepicker doesn't detect de-selection of dates. Here's my code for loading the dates from firebase:
func loadSavedDates() {
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        let uid = try! AuthenticationManager.shared.getAuthenticatedUser().uid
        print("User ID: \(uid)")
        print(widget.id.uuidString)
        
        db.collection("spaces")
            .document(spaceId)
            .collection("dates")
            .document(widget.id.uuidString)//widget.id.uuidString
            .getDocument {document, error in
                if let document = document {
                    if let dateStrings = document.data()?[uid] as? [String] {
                        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
                        self.savedDates = dateStrings.compactMap { dateFormatter.date(from: $0) }.sorted()
                        let calendar = Calendar.current
                        self.selectedDates = Set(self.savedDates.map { calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: $0) })
                        for component in selectedDates {
                            print(component.isValidDate)
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    print("Document does not exist")
                }
            }

This is an example of terminal output after dates are loaded and I select "July 24th" in the multidatepicker:enter image description here, in the first line it prints the loaded the array of dates, and in the second line after I press July 24th on the multidatepicker it just adds it to the array again instead of removing it.
As you can see, I believe I am setting the selectedDates array correctly with datecomponents. Is there a problem with my code or is there just no way to pass dates from Firebase into multidatepicker?

We can't see your source data in Firestore, so we don't know what this code is going to do with that data.  Please edit the question to show the actual data you're working with. Also it might be good to log some of that data in your code and show us the logging output so we can follow along.  There should be enough information in your post so that anyone can copy it and observe the same unexpected result that you're observing.

The error is telling you that in your data, eg savedDates in List(savedDates, id: \.self) { ...} or where you have a ForEach,
has dates with same values (occurs multiple times ....). Meaning your dates components, have the same values.
Do not use DateComponents use your own struct MyDateComp: Identifiable {...} where you create an unique id = UUID() for each.

Use [.calendar, .era, .year, .month, .day] instead of [.year, .month, .day] because that is the DateComponents format MultiDatePicker expects. Then selection will work correctly.

thanks so much, I'm new to StackOverflow so I can't upvote your reply but I appreciate the assistance, it worked. Thanks!

@JoshuaShen You're welcome! You should be able to accept the answer using the checkmark.
